# JAVA 1.8 Autowire : No unique bean

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a project in Java 1.6 and I have to pass in java 1.8.

I get this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.services.TicketManager net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.integration.itest.EndToEndTestCase.ticketManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.services.TicketManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [ticketManager, proxiedTicketManagerImpl]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.services.TicketManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [ticketManager, proxiedTicketManagerImpl]

Exception in thread "ActiveMQ ShutdownHook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/transport/vm/VMTransportFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:518)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.containerShutdown(BrokerService.java:1754)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService$4.run(BrokerService.java:1732)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 3 more
```

My class test :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/application-context.xml" })
public class EndToEndTestCase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ticketManager")
    private TicketManager ticketManager;

    /**
     * This test relies on the proxied ticketManager (stub) to send the NLV
     * buffer on the bus. The deployed skeleton intercepts the message,
     * transform it and delegates the process to the actual bean.
     */
    @Test
    public void test1() {...
```

And the appContext :

```
    <!-- defines which bean are service requests delegated to  -->
    <alias name="proxiedTicketManagerImpl" alias="ticketManagerImpl" />

    <!-- defines which bean are response requests delegated to  -->
    <alias name="proxiedTicketResponseImpl" alias="ticketResponseImpl" />
    <bean id="telecomReportingMethodInvocationInterceptor"
        class="net.amm.noc.integration.itest.MethodInvocationInterceptor">
        <property name="channel" value="TICKET-MANAGER" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="proxiedTicketManagerImpl" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
        <property name="target">
            <bean
                class="net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.mock.TicketManagerMock">
                <property name="ticketResponse" ref="ticketResponse" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>telecomReportingMethodInvocationInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="proxiedTicketResponseImpl" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.mock.TicketResponseMock" />
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>telecomReportingMethodInvocationInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="ticketManager" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interfaces" value="net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.services.TicketManager" />
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="net.amm.noc.telecom.reporting.services.TicketManager" />
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="java.lang.Object" />
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>telecomReportingServiceInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="telecomReportingServiceInterceptor"
    class="net.amm.noc.integration.client.aop.ServiceInterceptor">
    <property name="serviceMessageEncoder" ref="telecomReportingEncoder" />
    <property name="serviceCaller">
        <bean class="net.amm.noc.integration.mep.client.MepServiceCaller">
            <property name="responseListener" ref="telecomReportingResponseListener"></property>
            <property name="contextFactory">
                <bean
                    class="net.amm.noc.integration.mep.client.MepServiceClientContextFactory"
                    init-method="init">
                    <property name="serviceDefinition">
                        <bean
                            class="net.amm.noc.integration.mep.service.GenericServiceDefinition">
                            <property name="category" value="NOC" />
                            <property name="name" value="TEL_REPORT" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Does anyone can help me solve this problem?
For information, it's OK with Java 1.6
Thank you.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory`. Looks like a classpath problem.

Comment: It's very strange, this exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) is present half the time. I think the real problem is "No unique bean of type...".

Comment: **Caused by**. There's a reason for that phrase.

Comment: In  my world it looks like two problems. The first is that there are two candidates for autowiring by the name _ticketManager_ in the spring container. Then you also have a problem with `VMTransportFactory` not being in the classpath.

Comment: I agree, there are 2 different problems. For autowiring, I don't have 2 _ticketManager_ , but one _ticketManagerImpl_ and one _ticketManager_.

Comment: Looks like the @Qualifier does not pick up the wanted bean. Could you please try to explicitly specify the name attributes on the two beans in question? Apart from the id attributes?

Comment: I think the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError happens when the boot of the spring container is cancelled due to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and the VM is getting shutdown. Therefore, it is caused, and not the cause of the initial problem. Nevertheless, it might be usefull to fix that too.